# Is it possible to modify this command to use with the console in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I use this command because it allows me to sync the Geth blockchain to an external SD card rather than to the internal hard drive:

geth --datadir /media/user/sdcard/chaindata --ipcdisable

However, if there was a way to use it with the console it would be even better.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

geth console --datadir /media/user/sdcard/chaindata --ipcdisable

Is it possible to use the command with the console and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for you:

```
geth --datadir /media/user/sdcard/chaindata --ipcdisable console
```

The `console` and `attach [endpoint]` commands should always be at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put console after the options, the help command tells you that :

```
➜  ✗ geth --help
NAME:
   geth - the go-ethereum command line interface

USAGE:
   geth [options] command [command options] [arguments...]

(------cut------)

COMMANDS:
console      Geth Console: interactive JavaScript environment

(------cut------)
ETHEREUM OPTIONS:
  --datadir
```